# Key error in get_popular () and get url_post

Tags: python-2.7, machine-learning

```
from pydelicious import get_popular,get_userposts,get_urlposts

def initializeUserDict(tag,count=5):
    user_dict = {}
    # get the top count' popular posts
    for p1 in get_popular(tag=tag)[0:count]:
        # find all users who posted this
        for p2 in get_urlposts(p1['url']):
            user = p2['user']
            user_dict[user] = {}
    print user_dict # return a dictionary with some users, each referencing an empty dictionary waiting to be filled with links.

delusers = initializeUserDict('Programming')
```

when I run this script, I get a None dictionary,  {'': {}}. It is not supposed to be a none dictionary, there should be user names in it.

Why this happens? Thanks.

Comment: did you try to debug it? add this line `print p2['user']` below innermost loop. see what does it print?

Comment: @GauravJain I have tried and it returns [{'extended': '', 'description': u'something went wrong', 'tags': '', 'url': '', 'user': '', 'dt': ''}].

Comment: it clearly says that there is no value for `user` key. its null string, right?
thats mean you are not getting expected data from `get_urlposts` method. try to backtrack and debug it.

Comment: @GauravJain. But the thing is,  first I run x = get_popular('programming')[0], it returns {'extended': u'', 'description': u'Cello \u2022 High Level Programming C', 'tags': u'cello', 'url': u'http://libcello.org/home', 'user': u'', 'dt': ''}
Then I run  y = x['url'], z = get_urlposts(y),  now it returns [{'extended': '', 'description': u'something went wrong', 'tags': '', 'url': '', 'user': '', 'dt': ''}]
You can see there has information in x, but somehow, after the procedure of get_urlpost, the information is gone